# Angularjs - Time difference between my data time and CURRENT TIME

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display the time difference between my {{trade.timer}} and the current time but coudn't succeed after many tries.

I am looking to make the $scope.gains[i].timer = vtime - "CURRENTTIME"

Here is my code:

```
$scope.updatetimerValue = function (timerValue){
    $.each(timerValue, function(k, v) {
        for (var i =0; i < $scope.gains.length ; i ++) {
            if($scope.gains[i].orderid == v.orderid){
                $scope.gains[i].timer = v.time;
            }
        }
    });

}


<td>{{gain.timer | date: 'HH:mm'}}</td>
```

Any idea?
Note: v.time time format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: What's the format of your data time? Look also at the http://momentjs.com/ lib. It might be helpful to work with dates and times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get date difference between two days with basic javascript.

```
var date = new Date('10/27/2014');
var currentDate = new Date();
var milisecondsDiff = date-currentDate;
var secondsDiff = miliseconds/1000;
var minutesDiff = seconds/60;
var hoursDiff = minutes/60;
var daysDiff = hours/24;
```

Also I suggest don't mix up AngularJS and JQuery.
And instead `$.each` use the `angular.forEach`

```
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
///
});
```

or even better to use simple `for` loop, because it works faster.

Comment: This is of limited value for dates that may not of originated in javascript